# Getting connected user's information in Parse Server LiveQuery

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is there any way to get live query's connected user's information in the parse server? I want to receive user details and do some operation when he gets connected/disconnected via LiveQuery on the server-side.

I have already looked into the **onLiveQueryEvent** in Parse Cloud Code but it only gives the subscribed and connected user's count - not the actual user object.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do that. You should open an issue/send a PR in Parse Serve repo. It seems to be easy to be included. You'd just need to add the user information in this call [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/ce7ff2ca441da2956f779e7d41dc42da2db01c7d/src/LiveQuery/ParseLiveQueryServer.js#L686). Meanwhile you can call a cloud code function from client to notify server that the client confirmed the subscription and then perform the operation you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been added in Parse-Server 3.8.0

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/5927

You can get the sessionToken of the user.